# Inserir emoji no input do html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, chat

Gostaria de sabe pq quando insiro o codigo do emoji em um input no html não aparece o emoji e sim o código hexadecimal, se eu inserir o codigo em qualquer area no html funciona menos no campo input. Tentei inserindo no VALUE mas sem sucesso. Alguém saberia me informar

```
<input type="text" id="send_msg" name="message" class="write_msg" value="&#x1f603;" role="image" placeholder="Digite aqui sua mensagem" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `<meta charset="UTF-8">` para que haja consistencia na aparencia do emoji entre plataformas.

HTML

```
<input id='usrInput' value=''>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].value = String.fromCodePoint(0x1F354);
```

Comment: Origado brother, vou tentar aqui e volto com resultado